# Overwriting the values of li elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I have created this code that creates li element with input value after submitting the form. But the problem is when it creates the li and you start typing in the input again it begins to overwrite all the li elements

```
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [form, setForm] = useState("")
  let [tobuy, setTobuy] = useState([])
  const listOfLi = tobuy.map((i) => <li key={i}>{form}</li>);

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTobuy( [...tobuy , form])
    event.target.reset()
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setForm(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className='page'>

      <div className='heading'>
        Shopping List
      </div>

      <div className='buy-box'>

        <div className='to-buy'>Items to buy</div>

        <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" className='input' required onChange={handleChange}/>
          <button type="button" className='button' onClick={handleSubmit}>Add</button>
        </form>

        <div>
          {listOfLi}
        </div>

      </div>
      

    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` state is being used for the value of each `li` element, and `setForm` is called with each change of the input. Therefore, when something is typed in the input, `form` is updated to the current state of the input element.

React will re-render the component whenever the input is changed, and therefore re-render all of your `li`s with the current value of `form`. Since that also is changing with each input change, *all* `li`s will have the current value held in `form`.

You are accessing the value you need in your map. Try using that instead of the current `form` value.

Comment: Okay but can you show me how exactly should I do it because I am confused about this

Comment: @Kristian Change the callback return to `<li key={i}>{i}</li>`. You may want to read up on the documentation for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [caveats of setting React component state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats) if this is confusing.